# How to append a single labeled tick to x-axis using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a simple plot set up in matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
p=ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [10,9,8,7,6])
```

How could I add a tick to the x-axis at the value 1.5 with the label "here is 1.5"?

I understand that I could use `plt.xticks()`, but then I would need to specify *all* ticks and labels.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=range(10)
y=range(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
p=ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks([1.5])
ax.set_xticklabels(["Here is 1.5"])
fig.show()
```

[image]

If you want to add an additional x-tick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=range(10)
y=range(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

p=ax.plot(x,y)

xt = ax.get_xticks() 
xt=np.append(xt,1.5)

xtl=xt.tolist()
xtl[-1]="Here is 1.5"
ax.set_xticks(xt)
ax.set_xticklabels(xtl)

fig.show()
```

[image]
You can play around with label rotation if you need.